# jQuery preventdefault clears $_POST

Tags: jquery, post, preventdefault

I am trying to add a jQuery modal dialog to confirm a form. Searched around and found some code that looked promising and also seemed to work. Dialog pops up and submits the form when I confirm. However, the $_POST array is empty.

Now, when I disable the e.preventDefault() function, the post array is fine. But then the dialog won't stay open. I played around with the code but could not fix it. Here is the stripped down page code:

```
<?php
   print_r($_POST);
?>
<html>
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css">
</head>
<body>
   <form name="formAnnList" id="formAnnList" method="post">
      <input name="btn_delete" type="submit" class="button" value="Delete">
   </form>

   <!-- Delete confirmation dialog -->
   <div id="delDialog" title="Confirmation">
      <p>
         <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 0 0;"></span> 
         Are you sure
      </p>
   </div>

   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function(){       
      $('#delDialog').dialog({
         autoOpen: false,
         width: 280,
         modal: true,
         resizable: false,
         buttons: {
            "Ok": function(){ document.formAnnList.submit(); },
            "Cancel": function(){ $(this).dialog("close"); }
         }
      });

      $('form#formAnnList').submit(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         $('#delDialog').dialog('open');
      });
   });
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas are welcome.
Best regards,
George

Comment: Your form has no inputs (except for the button), so it would be weird if the `$_POST` was not empty.

Comment: btn_delete should be in the array tho

Comment: The value of a button is only submitted when it has been clicked. `document.formAnnList.submit()` does not click a button ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's empty because `preventDefault()` stop method for submit your data. You can modify this to serialize data:

```
$("#formAnnList").serialize();
```

and then send it using ajax or post method manually.

**something that (not tested):**

```
...
buttons: {
            "Ok": function(){
                 $.ajax({
                     url: //url here
                     data: $("#formAnnList").serialize()
                 })
            },
            ...
         }
```

---

**preventDefault from jQuery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/):**

> If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be
>   triggered.

Comment: I forgot about popup? Or missed something else?

Comment: `document.formAnnList.submit()` - The form gets submitted as soon as the user clicks the ok button ^^

Comment: And it's wrong in my opinion because he call the submit trigger which call popup again? I'm not sure but for me that it work.

Comment: From the [official DOM specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-40002357): "The onsubmit even handler is not guaranteed to be triggered when invoking this method."

Comment: Your solution is fine per se, but it follows a completely different application logic. That could be a problem for the OP.

Comment: Motivation for this was simply to have a nicer dialog than the default confirmSubmit()

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your input I figured it out. Since preventDefault() is wiping out the form data, the approach is to not trigger the dialog by a an element that also submits the form at the same time. So I created a button of type="button" and gave it the id="btn_delete_confirm". Clicking it will open the dialog, and confirming the dialog will submit the form. I just added a hidden button to the form that functions as the delete event transmitted in the $_POST array.

Here is the changed code that works. You will see that the $_POST array contains the hidden button that I can now react on:

```
  <?php
     print_r($_POST);
  ?>
  <html>
     <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css">
     </head>
     <body>
        <form name="formAnnList" id="formAnnList" method="post">
           <input id="btn_delete_confirm" type="button" class="button" value="Delete">
           <input name="btn_delete" type="hidden" class="button" value="Delete">
        </form>

        <!-- Delete confirmation dialog -->
        <div id="delDialog" title="Confirmation">
           <p>
              <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 0 0;"></span> 
              Are you sure
           </p>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){       
           $('#delDialog').dialog({
              autoOpen: false,
              width: 280,
              modal: true,
              resizable: false,
              buttons: {
                 "Ok": function(){ document.formAnnList.submit(); },
                 "Cancel": function(){ $(this).dialog("close"); }
              }
           });

           $('input#btn_delete_confirm').click(function(){
              $('#delDialog').dialog('open');
           });
        });
        </script>
     </body>
  </html>
```

Thanks again. Always helps to talk to pros.
Best regards,
George